# how do i use paypal.minicart.view.bind(form);?

Tags: php, ajax, paypal

How do i use 
`paypal.minicart.view.bind(form);`

What exactly do I pass as a parameter? I'm using ajax to display the Paypal add to cart forms, but when i click add to cart, it redirects me to the Paypal website version of the cart instead of the 'pop up'.  Does anyone knows how to bind the forms after they're loaded? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with a little extra help from a colleague. For anyone running into a similar issue, here's the basic code in my AJAX-loaded page which allows me to trigger Minicart.js properly:

```
<div class="product-button">
    <form id='form' action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@minicartjs.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Product One">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0123456789">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="weight_g" value="240">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id='button' type="submit" value="USD 100.00">
    </form>
    <script>
        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            paypal.minicart.view.bind(form);
        });         
    </script>       
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't seems to be working for me, does php affect it in any way??

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough in PHP to answer your question, but anything could affect this functionality really, PHP, JS, even improper CSS can break it.

What worked for me was making sure the <script> above is triggered after the AJAX page has been loaded.